# How to choose adapter for view pager?

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I need to show images in **ViewPager**.

But I don't know which adapter to choose:

**1) PagerAdapter**

**2) Fragment Adapter.**

What is better for my task to display images?

Comment: Given as how PagerAdapter is an abstract class, I wrote a ViewPagerAdapter implementation. The source is [available here](https://github.com/ataulm/view-pager-adapter) (along with a [demo activity](https://github.com/ataulm/view-pager-adapter/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/ataulm/vpa/demo/DemoActivity.java)). Add gradle dependency using `compile 'com.ataulm:view-pager-adapter:0.0.1'` (you'll need to add JCenter as a repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just images then i would suggest just a Pager Adapter as there is no need for fragments.

Comment: I used Pager Adapter with List of View.

Answer (score 2):

Google's example uses a PagerAdapter, so I would use that

> ViewPagers use PagerAdapters as a supply for new pages to display, so
>   the PagerAdapter will use the fragment class that you created earlier.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager